# Change Result Link From Foreach php, with Javascript Not working is it possible?

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink, href

Hey I have a search results built in php (search.php) taken results from my mysql database.

When I get the results I need to change the href for the final display result from /articles/ to /news/ depends which case is the result and from which table it came from because the results of my query is from two different tables.

```
    <?php if ($news_id > 0 ) { ?>

  <script>


            var myElement = document.getElementById("search_link").href = "#/news/<?php echo $row['url'] ?>";

  </script>

    <?php } ?>

     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Is There a batter why of doing this maybe only with php without the java and only with php?
I just simply need to change the link its just not seems to work inside the foreach loop nothing is happening even tried without if statement the link wont change.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an element with the id "search_link" effectively exists on your page, your code is valid syntax-wise and should work.

So it seems your foreach loop is never executed but, with the piece of code you provided, it's impossible to tell why. 
(on a side note, if your search_link is displayed inside your foreach loop, you don't need javascript at all, but again this is pure asumption because it's impossible to tell with that code sample)

Comment: Hey Thank you for you help first of all. My search_link is just a simple href with the id search_link